# Chat Agent is online but the chat button on the community still shown offline

Tags: customer-community, liveagent, community-builder, service-cloud-console, chat

I have set up chat in our salesforce org and have configured chat button on the portal site. I have done the following things to get this enabled:

- Created a new queue from Service cloud (Chat with customers)
- Set the agent workload
- Enabled Chat
- Then added Embedded Service chat on the portal
- Added Skills to the queue

After doing the above I made the admin as 'Available' on the Omni channel in a console app and tested from the portal and it works fine. However, when I add a new user to the queue and assigned all the skills, I log in as this new user and make him 'Available on the Omni channel but the chat button on the portal still show 'Agent offline'

I have checked the Routing configurations and Presence configurations as well, The Routing configuration Unit of Capacity is set to 5.00 and Presence configurations Capacity is set to 20.

The new user is added to both Chat Agent configurations and the Queue, The new users profile has access to Chat Transcripts, Chat visitors and Chat Sessions objects.

I am not able to figure out why it still shows as 'Agent Offline' when the agent with the right skills is having status as 'Available'

[image]
[image]